# Calling a method on an object that is in an ArrayList

Tags: java, hashmap

I've been stuck on this question in an assignment in which I must "List the stations along a given subway line"
There are two Hash Maps:

```
private Map<String, Station> allStations = new HashMap<String, Station>(); // all stations, indexed by station name
private Map<String, SubwayLine> allSubwayLines = new HashMap<String, SubwayLine>(); // all subway lines, indexed by name of the line
```

I am trying to call the "getStations()" method, which is a part of the subwayLine class:

```
public List<Station> getStations(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(stations); 
}
```

On a subwayLine object which is linked to a button:

```
public void listStationsOnLine(){
    UI.clearText();
    List<SubwayLine> subwayLines = new ArrayList(allSubwayLines.values());
    for(SubwayLine s  : subwayLines){
        s.getStations();
    }
}
```

However, this does nothing. Is there anyway in which I can return the stations along the given subwayLine?

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger? See if there's anything at all in your `subwayLines` HashMap?

Comment: You have no output whatsoever within that for-loop. What do you expect to happen there?

Comment: You already return the stations - `List<Station>` is the result from `getStations()`, but you just discard it right after. Save it to a variable and do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `void` keyword in your method means that it does not return anything.
You might want to replace it with List and return it at the end of your method, like

```
public List<Station> listStationsOnLine(){
    UI.clearText();
    List<SubwayLine> subwayLines = new ArrayList(allSubwayLines.values());
    List<Collection<Station>> stations = new ArrayList<>();
    for(SubwayLine s  : subwayLines){
        stations.add(s.getStations());
    }
    return stations
}
```

Please note that you loop through all subwaylines and therefore your stations arraylist consists of all stations that are along *some* subwayline. So not a list of stations per subwayline. Also, I added a diamond operator to the arraylist call. That will automatically make an ArrayList of the type `Collection<Station>`. However, making a List of Collections seems not right here? You probably just want a List of `<Station>`.

Moreover, the call `s.getStations()` seems to yield all stations at subwayLine s? The description of your question seems to ask how to implement thát method.
In your question, you seem to prefer a list of stations for a given subwayline. That should then be input for your method, something like this:

```
public List<Station> listStationsOnLine(SubwayLine subwayline){
    UI.clearText();
    List<Station> allStations = getStations();
    List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Station s : allStations){
        if(s.onLine(subwayline)) {
            stations.add(s);
        }
    }
    return stations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to save your data in an arraylist again :

```
public void listStationsOnLine(){
    UI.clearText();
    List<SubwayLine> subwayLines = new ArrayList(allSubwayLines.values());
    List<Collection<Station>> stations = new ArrayList();
    for(SubwayLine s  : subwayLines){
     
        stations.add(s.getStations());

    }
}
```